# javascript Promise excution order

Tags: javascript, promise

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(() => console.log(2))
.then(() => console.log(3));

Promise.resolve()
.then(() => console.log(4))
.then(() => console.log(5));

console.log(1);
```

why above code Snippet result is `1 2 4 3 5` instead of `1 2 3 4 5` .

what is the execution order?

Comment: Promises are asynchronous so this is likely a race condition.

Comment: the callback queue is fifo. 3 and 5 can't be inserted into the queue until after 2 and 4 run.

Comment: There is no specified order other then 1 will always be first, 3 will always follow 2 but not necessarily immediately,and 5 will always follow 4, again, not necessarily immediately. Welcome to asynchronous code ;)

Comment: well, in this case it's pretty much guaranteed, but you'd be correct if this was an http request, or a db request, etc

Comment: the code is  copied from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises with some my modifications. I understand const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

wait().then(() => console.log(4));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2)).then(() => console.log(3));
console.log(1); // 1, 2, 3, 4  cause they stated  "Instead of running immediately, the passed-in function is put on a microtask queue, which means it runs later when the queue is emptied at the end of the current run of the JavaScript event loop " .

Comment: `.then()` handlers are likely run in the order they were queued and the order yours are queued is 2, 4, 3, 5, though if your code depends upon a specific order, you SHOULD code to force that order and not rely on specific queuing strategies.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It runs in this order because that's the order that the callbacks were entered into the callback queue.

Lets follow through what this code does:

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(() => console.log(2))
.then(() => console.log(3));

Promise.resolve()
.then(() => console.log(4))
.then(() => console.log(5));

console.log(1);
```

- First, the main code is ran, two promises are created and resolved, and two callbacks are added to the callback queue; callbacks 2 and 4. The queue is now [2,4]. Then console.log(1) happens and the function ends.
- Now that the function is done, the next callback in the callback queue runs, thus logging 2, that then pushes a new callback into the callback queue, callback 3. The queue is now [4,3].
- Next, callback 4 runs and logs 4, and that pushes callback 5 into the queue. The queue is now [3,5]
- Next, callbacks 3 and 5 each run in order, bringing the queue back to [].

If any of the functions were asynchronous, this order could have changed drastically based on how long each took to complete.

Comment: Thank you. Buy why [2,4] added into the que first instead of [2 ,3].

Comment: 3 can't be added until after 2 finishes because 2 might return a promise, it doesn't know until it runs.

Comment: Note: 2, (and 3,4 and 5) definitely returns a promise, the result of `.then` is always a promise

Comment: by 2 i mean callback 2, callback 2 doesn't return a promise (the .then of course does)